# jquery: change background color when div reaches a certain height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my sidebar to change color when the user scrolls down below a certain element. I want the background to change from transparent to black, but slowly so it looks like it's fading to black. Below I had some old code and I'm trying to modify it.

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowBottom = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight();
    $(".project").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      var objectBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();

      /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { //object comes into view (scrolling down)
        if ($(".sidebar").css("background-color","transparent")) {$(".sidebar").css("background-color","black");}
      } else { //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
        if ($(".sidebar").css("background-color","black")) {$(".sidebar").css("background-color","transparent");}
      }
    });
  }).scroll(); //invoke scroll-handler on page-load
});
```

The sidebar's background is transparent, but when you scroll below the div with the image, I need the background to turn black. It does this but it just snaps to black. How can I accomplish the fade effect? I tried .fadeIn and .fadeOut but the whole sidebar along with the menu items fade in and out. I also looked at trying .animate() but it doesn't work with background colors. Am I missing something simple? Below is the CSS.

```
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: 34px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 35px;
}

.sidebar a {
    padding: 20px 8px 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .sidebar {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to put an extra div that covers the area of the fading element. Then you fade in/fade out that element. Otherwise there is no simple and cross-browser way to animate the background colour. If you don't fancy this, google background colour animation libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to the CSS on your `sidebar` class so that it fades from one to the other. That might look like this:

```
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
```

The generalized syntax is `transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;`. The [Mozilla developer page on transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) goes into a lot more depth about how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but here's a thought.
Instead of toggling the background color on the scroll event, you could toggle between two separate CSS classes, one with the transparent background color, and one with the black background color. Then in those classes, add a transition delay property, something like this:

```css
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 130px;
    margin-top: 34px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 35px;
}

.black-background {
  background-color: black;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.clear-background {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

Then in your JavaScript you could do something like this:

```js
/* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      if (objectBottom < windowBottom) { 
        //object comes into view (scrolling down)
        $(".sidebar").removeClass("clear-background");
        if(!$(".sidebar").hasClass("black-background)
           $(".sidebar").addClass("black-background"); // reset both
      } else { 
        //object goes out of view (scrolling up)
        $(".sidebar").removeClass("black-background");
        if(!$(".sidebar").hasClass("clear-background")) // reset both
          $(".sidebar").addClass("clear-background");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```js
$( window ).ready(function() {
  
    var wHeight = $(window).height();

    $('.slide')
      .height(wHeight)
      .scrollie({
        scrollOffset : -50,
        scrollingInView : function(elem) {
                   
          var bgColor = elem.data('background');
          
          $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
          
        }
      });

  });
```

```css
body {
  transition: background 1s ease;
  background: #3498db;
}
p {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
.slide .inside {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 3em;
}
.slide .inside p {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  
  <div class="slide slide-one" data-background="#3498db">
    <div class="inside">
    <p>Statement 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-two" data-background="#27ae60">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Statement 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-three" data-background="#e74c3c">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Statement 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-four" data-background="#e67e22">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Statment 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-five" data-background="#9b59b6">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Have an awesome day</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2542/jquery.scrollie.min_1.js"></script>
```